# Rolling Quantile Bins

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna achieve the following:
I have some series/df of floats and now I wanna compute for each value in that series the quantile bin it belongs to with respect to some window in the past. Basically a rolling quantile bin calculation.

I have a solution, but it is incredibly slow

```
def rolling_q_scaler(df, window):
  scaled = df.rolling(window, closed="both").apply(
      lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=False, duplicates="drop").iloc[-1])
  return scaled.dropna().astype(np.int32)

s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100))
rolling_q_scaler(s, 10)
```

My data is of shape (717027, 327). According to my calculation I need to wait around 4-5 days for this to finish. Unacceptable.

Do you guys have any idea, how to fasten things up?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody was wondering. I ended up using Numba.

```
@njit
def calc_quantile_nb(a):
    n_smaller = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] <= a[-1]:
            n_smaller += 1
    return n_smaller / len(a)

@njit
def calc_quantile_bin_nb(a, quantiles):
  bin = 0
  q = calc_quantile_nb(a)
  for quantile in range(1, len(quantiles)):
    if q <= quantiles[quantile]:
      return bin
    else:
      bin += 1
  return bin
```

And then do a rolling calculation with calc_quantile_bin_nb.

Cheers